# Thread-safety simple

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have a list of Components in a multithreading environnment and if I do any operation on this list except add (I use the keyword synchronized on the list in this case) and get (the method called by a component is thread-safe), is that thread-safe?

```
public class Test {

   private final ArrayList<Component> myContainer = new ArrayList<Component>();

   public void add(Component){
      synchronized(myContainer){
          myContainer.add(Component)
      }
   }

   public void useComponents()
   {
      for(Component c : myContainer)
           c.use(); // method thread-safe
   }

   // no other operations on myContainer
}
```

Comment: Provide the necessary code to replicate your scenario. With the current description, the code could still be thread unsafe.

Comment: Allawys thread unsafe ? @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: `useComponents` is thread unsafe. Any other thread may add a new `Component` while you're traversing the inner elements of `myContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

In the current form, it is not thread-safe: The `useComponents` method could be executed by one thread. At the same time, another thread could call `add`, and thus modify the collection while it is being iterated over. (This modification could happen *between* two calls to `c.use()`, so the fact that the `use()` method is thread safe would not help you here).

Strictly speaking, this is not even restricted to *multithreading*: If the `c.use()` internally called `test.add(someOtherComponent)` (even if it was done in the same thread!) this would throw a `ConcurrentModificiationException`, because again, the collection is modified while being iterated over.

Thread safety (without safety agains concurrent modifications) could be achieved by simply wrapping the iteration into a `synchronized` block:

```
public void useComponents()
{
   synchronized (myContainer) 
   {
       for(Component c : myContainer)
           c.use(); // method thread-safe
   }
```

}

However, this would still leave the possibility of a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Most likely the `c.use()` call will not (and should not) modify the collection that the component is contained in (otherwise, one could question the design in general).

**If** you wanted to allow the `c.use()` call to modify the collection, you could replace the collection with a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`:

```
private final List<Component> myContainer = 
    new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Component>();
```

and then you could even remove the synchroniziation completely. But you should be aware of the implications: The contents of the list will be *copied* during each modification (hence the name...). This is usually used in cases where you have a small collection that is frequently iterated over, but which is rarely modified. (Listeners in all forms are a classic example here).

Comment: I would recommend using another approach with a different concurrent structure like `BlockingQueue` backed up by `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html package contains some collections that could *probably* be used instead. Based on the question title, I wanted to point out the main issue, and show the simplest alternatives (although they may not be the "best" ones for every application case)

Comment: I know, and my comment was just to tell you that you may add another solution to your current post.

Comment: And we're on Java 8, and closer to see Java 9. I recommend you to use the latest javadoc as well :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok, except that I am not sure about iterator behavior in useComponents() if you'll simultaneously add elements to the list.

Did you consider using [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead?